# Firebase certificate authentication

Tags: authentication, certificate, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have no interest in authenticating my clients as they are.

I do, however, want to make sure that anyone reaching my FireBase is authorized. Namely, that it's only via my Android app.

Could it be done somehow? I couldn't find any option or alternative in FireBase documentation.

The best approach I see is to have my app signed by a certificate, and aithorize itself using it.

Comment: I thought of the following workaround: create a gmail account with my app's certificate fingerprint as the password, and authenticate using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To authenticate your app, use FCM (but regretably, it requires a server code):

- Create an anonymous firebase account.
- send an FCM message to your server, with the firebase account uid.
- the server will create a node such as `/uids/$uid/enabled`.
- have a rule to require it, e.g.:

  `".read" : "root.child('uids').child(auth.uid).child('enabled').val() == true"`

The reason for the FCM message, is that in order to send such a message, the app should be "registered", which means the developer's signing certificate for the app is known. anyone attempting to send such an FCM message and not through your app will fail - even if someone re-sign (and probably modify) your app.

The drawback is, of course, you need your server to receive FCMs - which is very easy on the device, but harder on the server side.